# Could not get the value from time input field using Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am implementing the `jquery timepicker` in my input text field but which trying to read data from input field I could not get it. I am explaining my code below.

```
    <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right oditek-form" style="width:180px">Start Time :</span>
    <input type="text" name="start_time" id="start_time" class="form-control oditek-form timepicker" placeholder="Add Start Time" ng-model="start_time" ng-keypress="clearField('start_time');" >
    </div>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addFactorData();"  id="addProfileData" ng-value="buttonName"/>
```

my controller file is given below.

```
var dashboard=angular.module('easyride');
dashboard.controller('pickhrController',function($scope){
   $('.timepicker').timepicker();
   $scope.buttonName='Add';
   $scope.addFactorData=function(){
       console.log('start time',$scope.start_time);
   }
}
```

Here I am trying to read the `start_time` value but in console its showing `undefined` . I need to selected time value while button click.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is expecting a parameter but you are not passing anything from the template,

change it as

```
 $scope.addFactorData=function(){
       console.log('start time',$scope.start_time);
 }
```

Comment: No, That is not reason. After dropping the parameter there is again same issue.

Comment: That is a reaosn indeed! can you provide a working plunker for your issue

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to get it to work by adding this, hope this helps

```
$('.timepicker').on('changeTime', function(dateText, inst) {
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.start_time = $('.timepicker').val()
            console.log('start time',$scope.start_time);
        });
    });
```